# What's the better way for a complex animation in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-webview, android-animation

I'm trying to insert an animation in my app and I found two alternatives:

the first one is to use the "Drawable Animation" with the "animation-list", but my animation is made of 125 full screen frames and when I tried to start it the app crashed with the `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"`.
I tried to fix the problem increasing the heap size by setting the `android:largeheap="true"` but didn't work. 
Is a possible solution converting the images from jpg to png?

I found the solution here [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occur on the animation Loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264420/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-occur-on-the-animation-loading) and something here [Causing OutOfMemoryError in Frame by Frame Animation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692328/causing-outofmemoryerror-in-frame-by-frame-animation-in-android), but I didn't find a correct solution.

The second way is to create the animation in javascript/html5 and putting it in a webview, but I don't know if this would be a good solution for the majority of android devices and I don't know if it is possible create a communication bridge between the webview and the app.

I found this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript but I'm not sure if it will work.

So could you please give some idea on finding a way for complex animation in android?